# html5 audio not working properly with angular | ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, audio, html5-audio

problem: angularjs plays 2 times the same song at the same time with some seconds delay in between them, 
first time i call the music i do it like this:

```
 //preset sound
  var sound = true;
  var sound = localStorage.sound;
  var sound = eval(sound);

  $scope.icon = "ion-volume-mute";
  var audio = new Audio('sound/song.mp3');
  audio.loop = true;

      //change icon & sound based on localstorage variables
      if (sound == true){
          window.localStorage.setItem("sound", true);
          audio.play();
          $scope.icon = "ion-volume-mute";
          console.log(sound);
        }
        else{
          window.localStorage.setItem("sound", false);
          console.log("ëlse " + sound);
          audio.pause();
          $scope.icon = "ion-volume-high";
        }
  //let the user toggle the sound ( MUTE | Play)
  $scope.soundControl = function() {

    if (sound == false){
      sound = true;
      audio.play();
      $scope.icon = "ion-volume-mute";
      window.localStorage.setItem("sound", true);
      console.log(localStorage.sound);
    }
    else{
      sound = false;
      audio.pause();
      $scope.icon = "ion-volume-high";
      window.localStorage.setItem("sound", false);
      console.log(localStorage.sound);
    }
  }
```

this also sets a button for users where a mute or play icon is shown (also stores in localstorage for next use)

on another page i want to give the user another choice to keep using the music or stop it(keeps playing throughout pages).

I use the same sort of code for it

```
  //sound
  var sound = true;
  var sound = localStorage.sound;
  var sound = eval(sound);

  $scope.icon = "ion-volume-mute";
  var audio = new Audio('sound/song.mp3');
  audio.loop = true;

      //audio switch ( PLAY | PAUZE)
  $scope.soundControl = function() {

    if (sound == false){
      sound = true;
      audio.play();
      $scope.icon = "ion-volume-mute";
      window.localStorage.setItem("sound", true);
      console.log(localStorage.sound);
    }
    else{
      sound = false;
      audio.pause();
      $scope.icon = "ion-volume-high";
      window.localStorage.setItem("sound", false);
      console.log(localStorage.sound);
    }
  }
```

strange thing is now when you toggle the button, the music starts playing 2 times with some delay in between instead of muting it.

I tried removing the new audio part, but then just crashes the page because there is no audio file found.

Ideal it would just stop or start playing the existing music file. (this is across 2 different controllers)

Comment: When you do this: `var sound = true;
  var sound = localStorage.sound;
  var sound = eval(sound);` aren't you just reassigning the value of one single variable? So in one instance it's `true`, but all of the sudden it's stored as sound, but not true, then finally evaled but it is no longer stored as sound , nor was it ever true.

Comment: i tried making an if/else like this   if (localStorage.sound === null)
  {
    var sound = true;
  }
  else {
    var sound = localStorage.sound;
    var sound = eval(sound);
  }
but stil in the other page its starts a new song instead of working with the one from the first controller (also deleted the sound = true; part from the second controller ofc)

Comment: the first one keeps playing throughout pages, but the second one doesn't seem to recognize it being the same one

Comment: You fixed it? Great, you should answer your own question.  I noticed `ion` floating about, you should add the tag `ionic-framework` if you are using it.

Comment: awesome i will, yeah but i figured it wasnt relative to the framework. thanks for the help tho :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an controller thats around my view, i can put my stuff in 1 controller and that seems to work like a charm

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <div ng-controller="complete-app">
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And with the controller like this

```
app.controller("complete-app", function($scope) {
  $scope.icon = "ion-volume-mute";
  var audio = new Audio('sound/song.mp3');
  audio.loop = true;

  if (localStorage.sound === null)
  {
    var sound = true;
  }
  else {
    var sound = localStorage.sound;
    var sound = eval(sound);
  }

  //change icon & sound based on localstorage variables
  if (sound === true){
      window.localStorage.setItem("sound", true);
      console.log("sound " + sound);
      audio.play();
      $scope.icon = "ion-volume-mute";
      console.log(sound);
    }
    else{
      window.localStorage.setItem("sound", false);
      console.log("sound " + sound);
      audio.pause();
      $scope.icon = "ion-volume-high";
    }

  //let the user toggle the sound ( MUTE | Play)
  $scope.soundControl = function() {

    if (sound === false){
      sound = true;
      audio.play();
      $scope.icon = "ion-volume-mute";
      window.localStorage.setItem("sound", true);
      console.log(localStorage.sound);
    }
    else{
      sound = false;
      audio.pause();
      $scope.icon = "ion-volume-high";
      window.localStorage.setItem("sound", false);
      console.log(localStorage.sound);
    }
  }
});
```